# JIRA: How I can maintain project document

Tags: jira

I am using JIRA from a pretty long time and its good, but now I want to store all the project document in a single place like sharepoint (with version if possible).

Do I need to create a ticket and then attach to it?
OR
Is there any separate place for it in JIRA?

Comment: JIRA is a ticketing system and not a document management solution. While it might be possible to attach files to individual tickets I highly doubt that you'll end up happy with this approach.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should try using [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence), which is itself part of the Atlassian stack of software development/productivity tools. Confluence is a feature-rich document/knowledge sharing application which is somewhat comparable to SharePoint and offers great integration with Jira and its other sibling products).